# How to change default product type in the main metabox

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change the default product type in the main WooCommerce metabox from "Simple Product" to "Simple Subscription", does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Tried to use the filters I've found on the source-code but the closest I achieved was adding a custom product type, which obviously isn't what im after.

Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to change only name then you can do it from the plugin it self. This is located in `wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > includes > admin > meta-boxes > class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php` around line number 39. 

**NOTE :** This is not good way to do it.But If you are in hurry, you can select that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overlooked the correct filter, `default_product_type`, which is in the `output` method of the `WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data` class:

```
if ( $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'product_type' ) ) {
    $product_type = sanitize_title( current( $terms )->name );
} else {
    $product_type = apply_filters( 'default_product_type', 'simple' );
}
```

To filter it you'd do something like the following:

```
function so_27657057_default_product_type(){
  return "subscription";
}
add_action( 'default_product_type', 'so_27657057_default_product_type' );
```

You might want to check for the presence of a Subscriptions-specific class via some conditional logic, but if you know it will always be there that isn't such a big thing.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for the valuable suggestions. 
WooThemes support also added a solution which I ended up using, and it's working well:

```
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'mw_custom_product_type_change', 20 );
function mw_custom_product_type_change( $product_types ) {
    $new_array = array( 'booking' => $product_types['booking'] );
    $product_types = $new_array;
    return $product_types;
}
```

@helgatheviking approach seems really elegant too, so I will try it also. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The action 'default_product_type' mentioned by @helgatheviking, is not available anymore in Woocommerce.

@Luis Martins own solution only works if you wipe out the other product types.

I tried figuring out how to change the fallback product type of a new product from 'simple' to something else using a code hook,
but couldn't find my way through PHP.

Instead I achieved this with a bit of jQuery enqueued through the action 'admin_enqueue_scripts':

```
jQuery(function() {

    if ( document.location.href.indexOf( 'post-new.php?post_type=product' ) !== -1 ) {

        // If we have a page of an initially created product(an auto draft)

        // Force the default product type to 'variable'
        $( '#product-type' )
            .val( 'subscription' )
            .trigger( 'change' );

    }

});
```